# Angular passing data to modal and modal instance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a problem with passing data to my modal. I am using `ng-repeat` to display data from json file which looks like this

```
[
  {
   "id": 1,
   "userId": 0,
   "userName": "Krzyniu",
   "question":"abczxcvbnmasdfghjklqwewertyu",
   "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
   "voteCount": 18,
   "date": 7,

  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "userId": 3,
    "userName": "Pablo",
    "question":"def?",
    "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    "voteCount": 5,
    "date": 3,

  }
]
```

I want to use userId to open a modal that is displaying data from the other json file containing specific user profile data like activity level, number of comments etc.

I am using ui bootstrap and my controllers looks like that

```
    .controller('modalCtrl', function ($http, $scope, $uibModal, $log) {

      $http.get('json/users.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.items = data;
      });

      $scope.open = function (size) {

        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
          size: size,
          resolve: {
            items: function () {
              return $scope.items;
            },
            item: function(){
              return size;
            }
          }
        });

      };
    })
```

and that

```
.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items, item) {
      console.log();
      $scope.item = item;
      $scope.items = items;
      $scope.selected = {
        item: $scope.items[0]
      };

      $scope.ok = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
      };

      $scope.cancel = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
      }
    })
```

Comment: @Karim userId is random for each question and i want to open modal for specific user that contains his data

Answer (score 0):

This is work for a DataService.

As you can find in Jhon Papa's angular [styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1).

> All Angular services are singletons
>   That's why services are the best way to share data between controllers.

Take a look at the specific session about data services [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#data-services).